# Why does my screen blank out for the duration of the Grub boot menu?

Tags: grub2, shutdown, logout

Upon booting, when I should see the GRUB menu, my monitor simply says: "No optimum mode. Recommended mode: 1600*1200". If I wait for a short while, Ubuntu starts to boot and it reaches the desktop.

So I guess there is no video signal during that time, there's the grub menu but I cant see it and after the wait time everything is fine. I have the same problem when I log out for a short moment, before the log in screen is reached. and this also happens when i shut down ubuntu.

The VGA is an onboard NVIDIA GeForce 7025.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The graphical Grub menu does not appear to be compatible with your video card. So let's switch to a text menu instead.

1. Open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Paste the below, and enter your password when asked:

   ```
   sudo sed -i -e 's/#GRUB_TERMINAL/GRUB_TERMINAL/g' /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Then type `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot and hopefully you get a text menu instead of the screen just blanking out.

> *Explanation:* Here, *sed* simply uncomments the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` line, forcing  text mode

Comment: Thank you izx! Your solution solved the whole problem. even the log out and the shut down are fine now!

Answer (score 1):

I share the same video card.

Here is a solution:

1. Open up `/etc/default/grub` as 'root' (using `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, for example)
2. Uncomment the `GRUB_GFXMODE` line
3. Change the resolution to `800x600` (the lowest resolution for the video card)
4. Then type `sudo update-grub`

Here's what I'm talking about. This is an extract from `/etc/default/grub`:

```
 # The resolution used on graphical terminal 
 # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE  
 # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo' 
 # GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

Uncomment the last line and change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=800X600
```