# I have a grub menu display issue when booting up Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my screen blank out for the duration of the Grub boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161297/why-does-my-screen-blank-out-for-the-duration-of-the-grub-boot-menu)

When I boot up my dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the grub startup menu does not display on two of my computers using 
1. an HP w2207 monitor with an Asus Pent111 Computer.
2. my HP AMD64 using LCD TVs one was a Sony and the othe is an RCA 50 inch TV.

Not a problem on my laptops though. This is not a boot up issue just a display issue.The OSs still start after the default time or when I hit Enter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, maybe the solution there can help you too:
[Why does my screen blank out for the duration of the Grub boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161297/why-does-my-screen-blank-out-for-the-duration-of-the-grub-boot-menu)