# How to remove the graphical user interface?

Tags: virtualbox, uninstall, performance, gui

Okay my question is that, I want to run a heavy application, on a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) with just 2 GB RAM (Windows 7 32Bit Host has 4 GB, 3.5 GB effective). Initially I thought of installing Ubuntu Server 12.04.1, which doesn't come with a GUI, so I thought it would be efficient in performance, but I have only Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop.

My question is, is it possible to remove the GUI parts in Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (Not Server), keeping only the core OS, after installation in a virtual machine?

Or, is there anyway to improve the performance of the OS?

If you need more information, I am ready to provide.

I don't want the GUI or anything, even a small terminal window is fine for me, I can access files through FTP.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It is not needed to remove the GUI (unity, lightdm, compiz, etc.) from the system.

You can leave it and just make your default boot as a text mode and if once you need a GUI you can restore it easily.

open `/etc/default/grub` as root in your favourite text editor, for example `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` And change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
To `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` and update Grub.`sudo update-grub`
Your system will then always boot to text mode.

If you once want to use GUI you can easly start lightdm, the GUI:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

[Here](http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2009/07/21/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-run-faster-on-a-laptop/) are some hints that you may use to increase performance of your system.

Comment: +1 for *quick* reply. Let me try it out and see if that works! :) Also, will this perform better than having GUI and running it?

Comment: take your time and post results please

Comment: I have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`. Should I use `"text"` or just `text`?

Comment: Better to use `"text"`.

Comment: Awesome, got the command screen version just like Server. I just need to meddle with my IP Config and Network Proxy. See you then. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: So, now how do I shut down the system? When I am in the login screen, can I just power off the system?

Comment: You are welcome.use command line `sudo shutdown -h now` or `sudo halt`

Comment: @maythux Though [`halt` and `poweroff`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/halt.8.html) are usually equivalent, arguably it is preferable to use [`sudo shutdown -P now`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) or `sudo poweroff` to shut down *and power off* the system.

Comment: Is `sudo update-grub` still valid? I don't have it in 21.04

Answer (score 32):

None of these answers answers the user's question.

- Advising how to disable the GUI is not removing it.
- Advising how to use a different GUI is not removing it.
- Advising to use a different Linux distro is not removing it.

The commands to remove the GUI are:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will remove the Ubuntu Desktop meta-package and all associated packages.

If you're going to answer the question, answer the question.

Comment: The accepted answer gives pointers in a recommended direction. Just answering `sudo apt-get remove stuff` could cause more harm to the OP than you might think. Please avoid adding reasons to why you've added the answer, that is off-topic and is better off as comment.

Comment: I agree with @edwin. :)

Comment: if i want to enable it what should i do?

Comment: This method may or may not work: often packages that provide the GUI are depended on by other packages, such that the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage is not always the root of their "dependency tree."

Comment: Majik still has a VERY valid point!
When someone asks how yo remove the gui, any other answer than **how to actually remove the gui** is per definition off topic.
If someone asks "do i have to remove the gui?", feel free to elaborate on the pros and cons of the gui and/or different versions of it.

Comment: This did not work for me. Rebooted after both commands boots to the standard ubuntu desktop login, but then after logging in I'm left at a blank blue screen with limited right-click menu.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can install openbox, one of the most lightweight window managers available:

```
sudo apt-get install openbox openbox-themes obconf obmenu
```

This automatically adds an openbox session to the login menu. And this is its GUI:

[image]

Yep, that's it. Nothing more but a right-click menu. A GUI with an incredibly low RAM footprint, just like you want it.

Comment: Looks cool, but I am more and more interested in removing the interface itself, coz, I wanna run some huge heavy app, which I can access using my Windows host. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman if your problems is not ROM space but rather RAM+CPU, the correct question to ask is "How do I log into linux without a GUI", not how to uninstall it.

Comment: @Vorac Yea, sure... Now we have Vagrant and Docker, rendering this question totally useless.  And I have got a machine that's Intel Dual Xeon with 64 GB RAM. So... 