# Is it practically useful to decline GUI for a newbie in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

My Ubuntu is 12.04.

I have just started learning Linux (Ubuntu in particular).
To remember terminal commands quicker, I'd like to not use a GUI.

However, I can't launch installed programs because I don't know where they are.

For example, I have a PDF file. I know that there is a program to view such files.  If I was using a GUI I would just click on the PDF file and it would open in Document Viewer 3.4.0.

Then I would like to launch Firefox Web Browser. Even if I know it is installed, how to find the file to be launched using just CLI is a mystery to me.

Could you suggest anything?

Comment: how to disbale GUI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-gui-from-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: My suggestion is don't decline GUI completely. Sometimes you need it. Try learning commands and using GUI simultaneously. For learning commands, you can refer to answers given below :)

Comment: This is a very open question, so it's hard to find a definitive answer. But pertaining to your problems with opening files form the CLI in particular, I would advise you to use `xdg-open`, a CL tool that opens files always with their predefined default applications.

Comment: This may also interest you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application/126423#126423

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, for most of these programs it is enough to simply know their name. When installed from a repo, they tend to add themselves into your path, or a symbolic link to the applications binary is added into a folder in your path already.

Also, man (manuals!) is your best friend!

```
man apt-get | less
```

Then you can scroll up and down, line by line rather than having to go by entire pages, (depending on your version/distro, this may be the default functionality of man) it can be very useful when trying to get that next line of output.

And last, but definitely not least, if you are new to linux, your package manager apt-get, is going to be your best friend. For experience you should install some programs from source, but knowing your package manager and being able to search it will be invaluable as a time saver.

Hopefully this helps some.

Comment: _"pipe man output into something like less"_ - can you add a simple example for us noobs?

Answer (score 2):

Most of your executables are in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. For example, you can find firefox in `/usr/bin/firefox`.
Those two paths are in your $PATH, so you can choose your app with tab-completion

Answer (score 2):

As stated in other answers, usually when you install a package its executables are added to common paths, so if you know the name of the application you want to use, you just have to write its name.

If you want to know the command to execute a specific application this trick can help you:

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

this will let you click in any window you have currently open and probably get you the command needed to start that application. For example, clicking in a Document Viewer (pdf reader) window i get `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "evince", "Evince"`, being `evince` the command used to open Document Viewer. If it don't works you can try replacing `WM_CLASS` with `WM_COMMAND` or `WM_DESKTOP_FILE` (this last will show the location of the .desktop file).

If you need to know which application provides the "command" you can use `which`

```
which evince
/usr/bin/evince
```

But sometimes the program you are installing put their executables in some uncommon location. Take for example [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org). If you install any of the versions available in the repositories their executables are placed in `/usr/lib/postgresql/<version>/bin/`. If you try to execute `initdb` (a PostgreSQL command) the system will not be able to find the command.
In a situation like this you can use [apt-file](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apt-file) to search which package provides the `initdb` program and where it will be placed after installing the package

```
apt-file search initdb
<omitted results>
postgresql-9.1: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb
<omitted results>
```

Also you can use `locate` to try to find where the command you need is. Using again `initdb` as an example:

```
locate initdb
/etc/alternatives/initdb.1.gz
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb
/usr/share/man/man1/initdb.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/initdb.1.gz
```

Hope those tips help you.

Answer (score 1):

You must know the command to each application and you can just launch that application by wrirting the command in the terminal

For example to launch firefox web browser you can just write `firefox` in terminal

To open gedit the same or `sudo gedit` to save or read for a secured directory and like that

Answer (score 0):

**Practicality**

Let's tackle this question first. Command line is essential in Linux world. Many tasks *have to* be done through command line or at least are preferred to be done in, like debugging for instance. Certainly, you can go without learning command line, but you can have more control over your machine in command line instead of GUI. Plus you learn a lot.

For a newbie, the best way to learn command line is to **make your learning process practical**. For example, I am a college student, who is studying C programming right now. So far I've programmed exclusively in command line, using gcc compiler and nano text editor, and that's all I really need. I've learned a lot this way, much more when using GUI style applications (and don't even get me started on Microsoft's Visual Studio - yuck).

Another suggestion, that is also ties in with making things practical is, **find command line solution to action you'd otherwise do with GUI** . For instance, the internet connection sometimes drops at home, and I can't go to any website, even though network icon says connected. So I wrote a scrip that will turn wifi off and on, and network manager will automatically connect to my home network

```
#!/bin/mksh
printf "\n Turning wifi off";
nmcli nm wifi off; 
sleep 2; 
printf "\n Turning Wifi on"
nmcli nm wifi on; 
#printf "\n Gonna observe how Network Manager reconnects\n Press Ctrl+C when done ";
#sleep 2;
watch -n1 nmcli dev status
```

I frequently fall asleep in front of my laptop, so I wrote a script to shutdown computer an hour after I execute that script.

```
    #!/bin/mksh
sudo shutdown -P +60
```

This way I only have to type `shut` in terminal and my sudo password, and no the whole nine yards. Another question yesterday asked to manually change brightness, so at least for my own machine I wrote a script that will open the file that controls brightness in nano text editor.

```
#!/bin/mksh
printf " \n Entering file to change brightness in 3 seconds\n remember - no new line after number.  ";
sleep 3;
sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Do you see what I'm talking about ? All these commands can be done with GUI alternatives. But this way you learn command line with practical aspect. Like checking email in command line, or sending one, or checking battery power, or . . .(goes on into infinity)

And of course, **find solutions to questions posted here, on askubuntu.com** . Although I'm also still very new to Linux world (started with 13.10 in spring 2014), I've learned a lot by reading what others post and ask. It's very valuable to solve real-world problems.

**Some other suggestions** :

*First program to start*

If your only concerned with starting applications, you could use `Classic Menu Indicator` and `Gnome Do`. Gnome Do starts when you boot computer and is first thing you see when you log-in into GUI session. Type name of the app, and it will start. For instance, I saw your question on my phone, turned on laptop, logged in, typed "firefox" into Gnome  Do, and here I am - typing this answer.

*Opening a file without knowing which program to use*

In terminal (aka command line), you also could use something called `gnome-open` . For instance, if I wanted to open a pdf file called random.pdf, I'd type gnome-open random.pdf  and voila - Document Viewer(aka Evince) opens my pdf file.

What if you wanted to find out which program opened that file ? Well you could go to about or help tab in drop down menu for that progra OR, you could run `ps ax` in terminal. For instance, I opened a random text file with gnome-open, and it brought up some text editor, but i wanna know which it is. So , I executed ps ax

[image]

Do you see line with process 4149 ? It says  `gedit /home/sergiy/random` . So, my random text file was opened with gedit text editor.

And as other users pointed out here you can use `which` command. How about source files or binary files for that command (because everything in unix is a file)? Use where is command, e.g. `whereis bash`. Locate a specific file file ? no problem ! `locate random.txt`

*Learning command line in general*

Every type of learning needs sources. Make sure you research internet and read books. Personally, I started with very very very old Unix System V book, and now I have "[Ubuntu Linux Toolbox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118183525)" book, which is all about command line.

Now, I wanted to write something for Linux as my final coding project, so what I use now is [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) - an online book. Both practical and educational, and you still learn command line.

**Conclusion**:

Learning command is very rewarding, fun, and will give you greater appreciation of what's under the hood of your OS. It's like a car - sure you can drive without ever opening the hood, but  when a problem arises, you'll have idea about at least something of what you're doing, and don't have to run to a shop. Just remember what i said - learning has to be practical, and *you yourself* have to make it practical.

**Bonus**:
Here's some of the command line tools I love to use:

- elinks - this command line browser comes handy when i mess up my gui,
  and have nothing but command line in tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1).
- byobu  - sometimes it is nice to have bunch of indicators or tabs
  like in gui. Byobu gives you exactly that in command line
- moc player - very valuable when you mess up gui, and have to fix for
  hours, and while you do that - listen to music
- Htop - viewing processes, alternative to top
- nano - command line text editor. Most writing I do now is there
- olive - reading news in command line
- mutt and alpine - emails; take hours to configure, though.
- doc2txt - I'm pretty sure this item is part of another package. I usually use it to convert my professor's HW assignment into text i can read, in command line, of course

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add midnight commander ! Command line file manager !

Comment: Oh, and small note, mksh in scripts means i use Korn shell. You'd have to change that to bash, unless you're also using Korn shell