# Boot computer to text mode using kernel parameters

Tags: boot, kernel, lightdm, upstart, console

Referring to this question:
[How to remove the graphical user interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196603/how-to-remove-the-graphical-user-interface)

The answer of modifying /etc/default/grub to have GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text" would be great, but unfortunately I don't have GRUB. Can I achieve the same by modifying Kernel boot parameters manually, like from u-boot?

Comment: I am assuming that you already are aware of ctrl+alt+F1 thru F7. It is not the same but it definitely improves on the cpu overhead.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I need my computer to boot to text mode (without X) each time it boots. I don't want to uninstall graphical desktop as I see I may want to revert back someday.

Comment: But if you want the graphical desktop envoirement back, you can just install it again?

Comment: Correct, but it's a lot of packages to uninstall and then install again. I'd prefer more elegant solution. Actually I've done that uninstalling once, but there were some dependency issues, as desktop is tightly integrated with power saving and some other components, so there was no clean way to uninstall desktop. I wouldn't like to run to these issues again.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo sh -c "echo manual >> /etc/init/lightdm.override"`

To revert
`sudo rm /etc/init/lightdm.override`

From http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting
via https://superuser.com/questions/266040/how-do-you-disable-an-upstart-service-in-ubuntu-10-10#comment351951_266040