# Always boot to gui

Tags: boot, command-line, 12.04, gui

I've got an old that sits and does some of the grunt work in the house. I've recently got it running 12.04 from 10.x, and everything seems to be working brilliantly.

Unfortunately though, it only seems to boot to the GUI when a screen is attached, and drops to TUI when there isn't. Since I mostly log into it via RDP, I'd rather it booted to GUI regardless of whether it has it's own screen plugged in or not.

Is there a setting I can change somewhere to disable TUI boot?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command `startx` or `sudo service lightdm start` (whichever works) after logging in to start a GUI. If the `startx` this doesn't exist you should install it by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

To start it at login, you could add a .desktop file to `/xdg/etc/autostart` to run the command.

From here: https://askubuntu.com/a/202274/176889