# Presumed GRUB screen is "out of range". What do I press for windows?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my screen blank out for the duration of the Grub boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161297/why-does-my-screen-blank-out-for-the-duration-of-the-grub-boot-menu)

I was going to try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside my normal windows 7. Installed it from an USB.stick but now my startupscreen is complaining about it being out of range.
I've tried to push cursors and enter, but only found something about grub(?) and system recovery.
If someone could guide me through the nonvisible screenchoises I would be very happy!
(and if I can't get my win7 back, is there some way of recovering my files and stuff from inside ubuntu?)