# Can't see boot loader

Tags: boot, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my screen blank out for the duration of the Grub boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161297/why-does-my-screen-blank-out-for-the-duration-of-the-grub-boot-menu)

When I boot my computer I can't see the menu that asks me what OS I want to load. My screen is just black and I get an error message on my asus monitor "out of range." So now if I want to retrieve something windows I can't because I don't know where it falls in the list.

Is there way to fix this or is there a way to have it load windows as default and when I wanna use ubuntu I will just push up a bunch of times and hit enter.

Specs:
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Acer aspire (desktop)
Asus Monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using ubuntu grub loader try holding `shift` at system startup until you see grub menu options
to change boot order to windows use grub customizer ant set this parameter in options-predefined-**windows`**

[image]

Comment: I do this on the initial boot?

Comment: i do this after few second after starting pc just hold it once you turn it on.

Comment: That didn't work. nothing came up, I shut down the computer returned it on and held shift and ubuntu started normally.

Comment: If the user wishes to display the menu, hold down the SHIFT key as the computer official source https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing it dont work in case when ubuntu installed from wubi install

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I found the answer here: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/153046/71679

Comment: they won't let me answer my own question... they are making me wait 7 hours. Feel free to answer it for me haha.

Comment: then all you have to do is set windows boot to default with grub customizer as it is on picture

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

and set

**`GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`**

Let us know if this helps solve your problem