# Ubuntu and Xubuntu blank grub, boots fine

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

I had Ubuntu 14.04 (updated to 15.04) installed before and now have Xubuntu 14.04, both have the same issue. The grub menu is blank, as in there is no text, no sign that the grub is there aside from the 10 second timeout. In Ubuntu it was a purple screen that I got since the Ubuntu grub is pruple and now its black in Xubuntu. The os boots fine afterwards.

Macbook pro 8,1

Comment: Check this out. Uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL = console` from `/etc/default/grub` http://askubuntu.com/questions/161297/why-does-my-screen-blank-out-for-the-duration-of-the-grub-boot-menu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used Boot-Repair and that fixes the issue with the blank grub screen. More information about it can be found on the [ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this does, where to find it, and why you believe it to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the timeout:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for a line labeled: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and make sure it is set to 0.